# Is there a way to see your full Comments history?

Tags: support, comments, data-explorer

I want to find a question I commented on about two years ago.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 11):

Did you try looking at [your comment activity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/344211/smartcaveman?tab=activity&sort=comments)?

You can always simply page through the comments, but if you've got some idea of when/what you're looking for it might be faster to use a [comment related search on the data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=comment).

Comment: @smartcaveman If that question or the comment has been deleted, you're SOL far as finding it on your own goes. You can email us (via "contact us" at the bottom of any page), but we'd need something tangible to go on - like what the question was about, or perhaps what the comment said - to be able to dig it up.

Comment: I was looking for this as well, I must say the "Comment Activity" is kind of hidden, I would've never thought of that

Answer (score 1):

I've created the following [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1380974?startdate=2011-03-01&enddate=2011-04-01&qa=qa&UserId=344211) that allows you to enter your userid, a start and end date and whether you're looking for comments on a question or answer or both. When run it goes over your comment history  and shows some relevant meta data.

Note that, despite popular demand, you can't find deleted comments. That is not possible by the means offered in the other answer, aka your user profile, nor via SEDE. Either become a moderator or befriend a moderator if you are looking for a deleted comment of yours.

If you know a word or phrase the comment should contain then you can fork this query and add at then end `and c.text like '%my word%'`. I leave it as an exercise for the reader to parameterize that option as well.

```
select p.id as [Post Link]
     , p.lastactivitydate
     , p.owneruserid as [User Link]
     , case p.posttypeid 
       when 1 then 'Q'
       when 2 then 'A'
       else '?'
       end [Q or A] 
     , c.id as [Comment Link]
     , c.creationdate
from posts p
inner join comments c on c.postid = p.id
where c.userid = ##userid?344211##
and c.creationdate between ##startdate:string?2011-03-01## 
                       and ##enddate:string?2011-04-01## 
and p.posttypeid in (case 
                     when ##qa:string?q## = 'q' or ##qa:string?q## = 'qa'
                     then 1 
                     else null 
                     end, 
                     case 
                     when ##qa:string?q## = 'a' or ##qa:string?q## = 'qa'
                     then 2 
                     else null 
                     end)
```

This is what the result might look like:

[image: query result based on 4 parameters: userid = 344211, startdate = 2011-03-01, enddate = 2011-04-01, qa = q, shows 46 rows in a grid, post link, lastactivity, user, q/a, comment, comment date]

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Use the great [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by the wonderful [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).